# Heroku cli: Heroku create command hangs

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

**Heroku Create** command hangs while printing *installing core dependencies ...*
There are no errors, the process is continuously running. This happens as part of my **Heroku toolbelt installation**. In the website it is mentioned to use HTTP_PROXY before running heroku command, in case we are behind a firewall. I am not sure about that, is that the reason? Please help. I am using Mac El Capitan.